# escape backslashes from tikz/math string variable

Tags: tikz-pgf, data-structures

Using `tikz/math`, I'm trying to define a string variable containing LaTeX commands, and thus backslashes. The goal is to be able to concatenate such strings.

The following doesn't work :

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}
{\color{blue}test For Blue},
\tikzmath
{
  let \a = \color{red}my red string;
  print{\a};
}
\end{document}
```

My guess it that `tikzmath` is trying to interpret `\color` as an associative array and to access it with `red`, and thus fails there.

Such stuff as `\text{my text}` also won't work.

I would instead want `tikz/math` to pass to `tikz` or LaTeX a string containing those backslashes

Is this at all possible within `tikz/math` ?

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what output you wanted, so two versions

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}

{\color{blue}test For Blue},
\tikzmath
{
  let \a = \string\color\string{red\string}my red string;
  print{\a};
}


{\color{blue}test For Blue},
\tikzmath
{
  let \a = \noexpand\color{red}my red string;
  print{\a};
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [TikZ manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), section "56.2 Assignment":

> `let 〈variable〉 = 〈expression〉
>   ;`
>
> This keyword assigns `〈expression〉` to variable without evaluation. The `〈expression〉` is however fully
>         expanded using `\edef`. [...]

`\edef` does not respect LaTeX's protection mechanism. Thus the low level `\noexpand` is needed to prevent an expansion of `\color` at the wrong time:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}
{\color{blue}test For Blue},
\tikzmath
{
  let \a = \noexpand\color{red}my red string;
  print{\a};
}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]