# use of \noexpand in tikz/math associative arrays

Tags: tikz-pgf, data-structures

The following does not work in `tikz/math` :

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}
\tikzmath
{
  let \a = my black string ;
  let \b = my red string ;
  let \c{1} = \a{\noexpand\color{red}\b}\a;
  print{\c{1}};
}
\end{document}
```

even though it will upon replacing all instances of `\c{1}` by `\c`.

Some way to still do that for associative arrays ?

Cheers,

Comment: There are several and more robust ways for doing such jobs. I mean, without `\tikzmath`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a followup [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/335253/16967). Apparently `\edef` is used more often and `\noexpand` gots consumed, exposing `\color` again. A better way is therefore to use a robust definition made via e-TeX's `\protected\def`. Package `etoolbox` provides an interface via `\robustify`:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\color

\begin{document}
\tikzmath
{
  let \a = my black string ;
  let \b = my red string ;
  let \c{1} = \a{\noexpand\color{red}\b}\a;
  print{\c{1}};
}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]